# How can i loop over all comboBoxes controls i have and add the items of each comboBox to a List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried :

```
var comboBoxes = this.Controls
                  .OfType<ComboBox>()
                  .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox"));

foreach (var cmbBox in comboBoxes)
{
    CMBXWMICLASSES.AddRange(cmbBox.Items[
}
```

But inside the loop the foreach how do I add the Items of each ComboBox ?

This is a working code:

In the top of form1 i did:

```
List<string> CMBXWMICLASSES = new List<string>();
```

Then i added a method that make recursively process all controls and their children:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                                      .Concat(controls)
                                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
```

Then adding the items from each ComboBox in the constructor:

```
var c = GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox));
            foreach (ComboBox cc in c)
            {
                foreach (string ccc in cc.Items)
                {
                    CMBXWMICLASSES.Add(ccc);
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you show the names of the comboboxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
         List<string> Items = new List<string>();
        var comboBoxes = this.Controls
              .OfType<ComboBox>()
              .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox"));
        foreach (var cmbBox in comboBoxes)
        {
            foreach (var cmbitem in cmbBox.Items)
            {
                Items.Add(cmbitem.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not working i tried "comboBox" then "ComboBox" but in all cases there are no results in comboBoxes. I also tried for the test "cmbxOption" one of the comboBoxes name but it didn't found any results either.

Comment: Just to note you could change List<string> to List<object> and to away with the .ToString() - thus you should get the 'real' items

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me. I had to loop recursively process all controls and their children. I will add the code that is working for me to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all solutions with foreach and it raise an exception when casting. If you want to get all the strings in the ComboBox, the only code that worked for me is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
     string value = myComboBox.GetItemText(myComboBox.Items[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (ComboBox box in _boxList)
        {
            ComboBox.ObjectCollection _items = box.Items;

            foreach (var item in _items)
            {
                _itemsList.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The OP is actually asking how to add the items in all comboboxes to a list and has already posted code enumerating the comboboxes within a container.  Your code seems to do the same as the OPs?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    using System.Collections;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (var result in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
            {
                foreach (var values in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
                {
                    result.Items.Add(values);
                }

                result.Items.Add(result.Name);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AddComboItemsToList();
        }

        private void AddComboItemsToList()
        {
            var comboEntries = this.GetComboBoxItems(this.Controls, "comboBox");
            foreach (var comboEntry in comboEntries)
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(comboEntry);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<object> GetComboBoxItems(Control.ControlCollection controls, string cmbName)
        {
            var cmbs = controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(cmbName));
            var ret = new List<object>();
            foreach (var cmbBox in cmbs)
            {
                ret.AddRange(cmbBox.Items.Cast<object>());
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<string> ItemsList = new List<string>();
foreach (Control c in cntrls.Controls) // you can change cntrls.Controls to your container or if its the form that holds the combobox then use this.Controls
{
   if (c is ComboBox) // check if control is checkbox
   {
     ComboBox cmb = c as ComboBox
     foreach(var comboitems in cmb ) // add combobox items to list
     {
        ItemsList.Add(comboitems.ToString());
     }

   }           

}
```