# How to use for loop to read values from a set of comboboxes one by one using visual basic

Tags: winforms, vb6

I want to use a for loop to read the values from three comboboxes one by one using visual basic

Comment: Duplicate of this; [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739672/how-can-i-loop-over-all-comboboxes-controls-i-have-and-add-the-items-of-each-com)

Comment: VB6? VB.Net? VBA? WinForms? WPF? Please make sure to add enough info to your question and to use proper tags. I suggest you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic to have a better idea about how to ask a good question.

Comment: WinForms it is. Thanks :)

Comment: Your use of the 'visual-studio' tag is not really appropriate.  Can you change this to WinForms and VB?

Comment: VB6 doesn't normally use the term Winforms.  VB.net does.  So are you using VB6 or VB.net?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but ...

Private Sub Form_Load()

```
Dim Idx As Integer

' Add some items to the combo box
Combo1.AddItem "One"
Combo1.AddItem "Two"
Combo1.AddItem "Three"
' Now print out the combobox items
For Idx = 0 To Combo1.ListCount - 1
    Debug.Print Combo1.List(Idx)
Next Idx
MsgBox "Done"
```

End Sub